# Music is not playing on rails CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to play music on show page but i got a error like this.

`<%= audio_tag @music.music.url,:autoplay=>true,:controls => true %>`

I invoke your help.

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: Check the value of ```@music.music.url```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<%= audio_tag @music.music_url,:autoplay=>true,:controls => true %>
```